# Excel: Charting graphs for different row numbers

Tags: excel

I have a sheet with the following values

```
`DateTimeStamp      ||TicketCount ||Priority
15/10/2023 00:30:00      1             3
15/10/2023 00:35:00      1             3
15/10/2023 00:40:00      1             2
15/10/2023 00:40:00      1             3
15/10/2023 00:45:00      1             2
15/10/2023 00:45:00      1             3
15/10/2023 00:50:00      1             2
15/10/2023 00:50:00      1             3
15/10/2023 00:55:00      1             2
15/10/2023 00:55:00      1             3
15/10/2023 01:00:00      1             2
15/10/2023 01:00:00      1             3
15/10/2023 01:05:00      1             2
15/10/2023 01:05:00      1             3
15/10/2023 01:10:00      1             2
15/10/2023 01:10:00      1             3
15/10/2023 01:15:00      1             2
15/10/2023 01:15:00      1             3
15/10/2023 01:20:00      1             2      `
```

I want to chart in such a way that for priority 3, there was 1 ticket at the specific time stamp. How can I achieve this using Excel? Any advice?

I tried the 2-d clustered columns but that didnt work. I am unable to use the categories for charting. I want the timestamp in the x axis, and along the y axis a chart showing how many tickets are there with each category being a different color

Comment: Your data right now would throw a straigth line because there is a single ticket for each timestamp and priority. ¿Are you sure you want that?

Comment: apologies, there is more data.. this is just the top few I selected. As the day goes, the count increases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the comment right now it draws just a straigh line because the cound is 1 for each timestamp and priority.

Make a Pivot Table to sum Ticketcount for each timestamp and each priority and then make a chart based on pivot table:

https://imgur.com/a/MEsX3Uc

> [Create a PivotTable to analyze worksheet
> data](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/create-a-pivottable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576)